# User permissions on TFS folder

Tags: tfs, permissions

I have one folder in TFS and I have given rights as Contributor that's mean they can do check outs/check in/locks etc. But I would disallow them to delete any file or subfolder belonging to main folder. Please let me know if you have any idea in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You cant, but on the other hand a delete of a file only hides the file. In order to 'permanently delete' a file you need to run *tf destroy* on the file , and that requires the user to be a part of the tfs administrator group .

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. I think this is something you will have to manage by process and not technology I'm afraid.

Any operation (excluding a destroy) can be undone.

Answer (score 0):

As was already said, this can't be done with permissions. If you absolutely need a way to prevent this (and rolling back the delete afterwards is not enough), you have two possibilities:

1. use a **Checkin Policy** to warn the user that he should not delete elements. This can be overridden by the user, so it's not an absolute, but they know they may only do this with your permission. If they still check in without permission, you can still roll back. Biggest drawback: You need to distribute a dll file to all client PCs everytime the policy is changed, because the checkin policy is executed on the client.
2. set up a serverside pre-Checkin check. You can write against **TFS API** to react to different events, such as pre-Checkin, post-Checkin etc. In those event handlers you may perform checks, e.g. "is a delete operation contained in the changes the user wants to check in?" and make the operation fail if that's the case. This cannot be overriden by the user, but is a lot more effort to implement and maintain imho.

That said, I would propose setting up "checkin conventions" the users are supposed to adhere to, and roll back any changesets where they don't. Possibly supported by variant 1. to remind the user that what he is doing is not permitted.